# Centering elements inside Bootstrap grid when resizing window

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, resize

I'm struggling with making web page I'm working on resizable. I've succeeded to center elements by using margin properties, but as soon as I start resizing the browser's window my logo and ship images fall out of place, until it gets really small and falls down col by col in a row.
This is 15.6 inch screen when in full size. [![full size][1]][1]

And this happens when resized:

[!resized][2]][2]

And this is ok, when resized to minimum width: 
[![min-width][3]][3]

I'd like to avoid situation in the 2nd picture, while maintaining the look for full-sized windows and minimum width windows. How should I do that, I've always struggled with positioning elements the way I want for every window heigth/width so I wanna master it once and for all through this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with following css for images of ships:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post what kind of code you have so far for this? 
As I see you should have three different containers here - first one would be the picture of first ship, second one would be Battleship Logo and the form container and the third one is ship container. 
If you are doing this with bootstrap you should have code like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first_ship col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="http://www.vache.me/dobule/img/favorites_3.jpg" alt="Ship Image">
      </div>
      <div class="battleshipLogin col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center">Battleship</div>
        <div class="form_container text-center">
          <input type="text">
          <input type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second_ship col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="http://www.vache.me/dobule/img/favorites_3.jpg" alt="Ship Image">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```